# Symfony2 (2.3) birthday field set default value in twig (form_widget)

Tags: forms, twig

i can't figure out how to set a default vaule to a birthday field in symfony.

for text field this works:

```
{{ form_widget(form.name, {'value' : 'Max' }) }}
```

is it possible to set a date default value? something like:

```
{{ form_widget(form.birthday, {'value' : '02.03.1980' } )}}
```

symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the hint (see data field). This works with choice. I set the default date in the controller and not in the twig template.

```
        $formAntragssteller = $this->createForm(new StandardType(), $antragssteller)
            ->add('geburtsdatum', 'birthday', array(
                'widget' => 'choice',
                'attr'  => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ),
                'label' => 'Geburtsdatum',
                'input' => 'string',
                'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
                'empty_value' => array('year' => 'Jahr', 'month' => 'Monat', 'day' => 'Tag'),
                'data' => '1984-04-04'
                ));
```

Answer (score 0):

"value" has nothing to do with the form type, but only with the internal widget template handling

you need to match the right widget via the "widget" word in the add method of the form builder

i.e. if you set ['widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy'] value is for sure in the form of '02-03-1980'

[birthday field tipe - widget paragraph](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html#widget)